# html: FBML namespace

Tags: asp.net, fbml

We are using application with integrated Facebook "login" functionality. For some reason, app crashes for IE 7 browser only. If in master page we add:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

everything starts working fine. Does that mean we are using fbml objects somewhere? If so, it is unclear - why it is working for rest of browsers... And as I remember starting from June 6
facebook will not support fbml anymore. In that case, is that ok to have refernce to

```
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml? Will it work after June 6?
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Peter.

Comment: what do you mean by crashes? any errors?

Comment: IE7 browser just crashes. Closed.

Answer (score 0):

FBML and XFBML are different.

FBML will be removed on June 6th not XFBML.

You can use this as your namespace going forward

`xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"`